# Why CREATE [relation] create 2 empty nodes in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I first create this 2:

```
CREATE (user1:Person {name:"User1"})

CREATE (user2:Person {name:"User2"})
```

And when I try

```
CREATE (user1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(user2)
```

It creates 2 empty nodes with no name nor anything related by the FOLLOW, but both nodes "User1"and "User2" are never blessed by my simple intention of relating them.

Why is this simple thing not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are processing the statements separately. The `user1` and `user2` are identifiers that apply to a specific cypher statement. By the time you execute the last statement cypher no longer has a reference for `user1` and `user2`.

You could write

```
match (u1:Person {name:"User1"}), (u2:Person {name:"User2"})
create (u1)-[:FOLLOWS]->(u2)
```

and that would find the nodes that you had previously created and join them with the `:FOLLOWS` relationship.

So when you just specified the identifiers int eh create statement it would match every node and join them.